# Performance of Lazy in F#

Tags: performance, f#, lazy-evaluation

Why is the creation of `Lazy` type so slow?

Assume the following code:

```
type T() =
  let v = lazy (0.0)
  member o.a = v.Value

type T2() =
  member o.a = 0.0

#time "on"

for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
  T() |> ignore

#time "on"

for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
  T2() |> ignore
```

The first loop gives me: `Real: 00:00:00.647` whereas the second loop gives me `Real: 00:00:00.051`. Lazy is 13X slower!!

I have tried to optimize my code in this way and I ended up with simulation code 6X slower. It was then fun to track back where the slow down occurred...

Comment: What did you expect? Lazy to be quicker? Lazy is relying on the System.Lazy class and in there it handles ThreadSafety

Comment: Not quicker but definitely not that slower :)

Comment: Lazyness never pays off, right? :)

Comment: While the Lazy version is slower, it is not significantly slower, you are losing 60 ns per call to Lazy. Unless you are doing something very contrived, you are never going to notice that overhead.

Comment: @Guvante: I really felt the overhead. I used it in the constructor of a 3D vector type. A simulation that heavily uses the vector type went from ca. 2 sec per step up to 10 seconds per step just because of the Lazy value in the constructor of the vector type...

Comment: @OldrichSvec: Contrived was a strong word, I just meant out there. Your performance hit was almost certainly not the construction of the Lazy class. Instead it was from the dereferencing of the Lazy instances. Lazy is a class, so is stored as a reference in an array. In contrast, double is a struct, so is stored in place. This can make an incredible difference when doing large computations, as a single vector could end up on 4 different pages in RAM with Lazy.

Comment: I will note that if you actually test access time + creation time lazy is not so bad - I see about 2x difference rather that 13x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lazy version has some significant overhead code -

```
 60     .method public specialname
 61            instance default float64 get_a ()  cil managed
 62     {
 63         // Method begins at RVA 0x2078
 64     // Code size 14 (0xe)
 65     .maxstack 3
 66     IL_0000:  ldarg.0
 67     IL_0001:  ldfld class [FSharp.Core]System.Lazy`1<float64> Test/T::v
 68     IL_0006:  tail.
 69     IL_0008:  call instance !0 class [FSharp.Core]System.Lazy`1<float64>::get_Value()
 70     IL_000d:  ret
 71     } // end of method T::get_a
```

Compare this to the direct version

```
 .method public specialname
130            instance default float64 get_a ()  cil managed
131     {
132         // Method begins at RVA 0x20cc
133     // Code size 10 (0xa)
134     .maxstack 3
135     IL_0000:  ldc.r8 0.
136     IL_0009:  ret
137     } // end of method T2::get_a
```

So the direct version has a load and then return, whilst the indirect version has a load then a call and then a return.

Since the `lazy` version has an extra call I would expect it to be significantly slower.

**UPDATE:**
So I wondered if we could create a custom version of `lazy` which did not require the method calls - I also updated the test to actual call the method rather than just create the objects.  Here is the code:

```
type T() =
  let v = lazy (0.0)
  member o.a() = v.Value

type T2() =
  member o.a() = 0.0

type T3() = 
  let mutable calculated = true
  let mutable value = 0.0
  member o.a() = if calculated then value else failwith "not done";;

#time "on"
let lazy_ = 
  for i in 0 .. 1000000 do
    T().a() |> ignore
  printfn "lazy"
#time "on"
let fakelazy = 
  for i in 0 .. 1000000 do
    T3().a() |> ignore
  printfn "fake lazy"

#time "on"
let direct = 
  for i in 0 .. 1000000 do
    T2().a() |> ignore
  printfn "direct";;
```

Which gives the following result:

```
lazy
Real: 00:00:03.786, CPU: 00:00:06.443, GC gen0: 7

val lazy_ : unit = ()


--> Timing now on

fake lazy
Real: 00:00:01.627, CPU: 00:00:02.858, GC gen0: 2

val fakelazy : unit = ()


--> Timing now on

direct
Real: 00:00:01.759, CPU: 00:00:02.935, GC gen0: 2

val direct : unit = ()
```

Here the `lazy` version is only 2x slower than the direct version and the fake lazy version is even slightly faster than the direct version - this is probably due to a GC happening during the benchmark.

Comment: You are right. I just did not expect it to be that significantly slower. Now I will be more careful when using 'Lazy' type ;)

Comment: You may want to add a note about the scale of this, as a random reader may not notice that you are talking about 60 ns per call to Lazy, and only see the 13x.

Answer (score 2):

*Update int the .net core world*

A new constructor was added to Lazy to handle constants such as your case. Unfortunately F#'s `lazy` "pseudo keyword" always (at the moment!) will wrap constants as functions.

Anyway, if you change:

```
let v = lazy (0.0)
```

to:

```
let v = Lazy<_> 0.0 // NB. Only .net core at the moment
```

then you will find that your `T()` class will only take ~3 times your `T2`.

(What's the point of having a lazy constant? Well means that you can use Lazy as an abstraction with quite little overhead when you do have a mix of constants and real lazy items...)

...and...

If you actually *use* the created value a number of times then the overhead shrinks further. i.e. something such as:

```
open System.Diagnostics

type T() =
  let v = Lazy<_> 0.1
  member o.a () = v.Value

type T2() =
  member o.a () = 0.1

let withLazyType () =
    let mutable sum = 0.0
    for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
        let t = T()
        for __ = 1 to 10 do
            sum <- sum + t.a()
    sum

let withoutLazyType () =
    let mutable sum = 0.0
    for i in 0 .. 10000000 do
        let t = T2()
        for __ = 1 to 10 do
            sum <- sum + t.a()
    sum

let runtest name count f =
    let mutable checksum = 0.
    let mutable totaltime = 0L
    for i = 0 to count do
        if i = 0 then
            f () |> ignore // warm up
        else
            let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew ()
            checksum <- checksum + f ()
            totaltime <- totaltime + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
    printfn "%s: %4d (checksum=%f for %d runs)" name (totaltime/int64 count) checksum count

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    runtest "w/o  lazy" 10 withoutLazyType
    runtest "with lazy" 10 withLazyType

    0
```

brings the difference in time to < 2 times.

NB. I worked on the [new lazy implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/8963)...